# Status indicator webpart fails on page edit

Tags: web-part

I have a status indicator webpart on two different Home.aspx pages in my site collection, both pointing to the same status list.  The main site contains another site, and the sub-site is where the status list is saved and maintained.

When I edit Home.aspx for either site this error message appears in the status indicator webpart right above the column headers:

> 25717|updatePanel|ctl00_m_g_957c8545_a4e4_469a_acf6_6fcd4be7d219__upPanel|

After modifying the page and saving it all of the webparts disappear and the page can't be reloaded or it returns an error box.  In order to change the page I have to go to All Site Content and restore a previous version of the page in question.

Why does this happen?  How can I correct this?

**Edit:** Here's an interesting development.  I re-added the webpart and saved the page, then went back in and made some random change to the text on the page, and while I still got that string of text in the webpart that I think indicates an error the page saved properly and displayed my changes with no problem.  Could it be that the order in which the webparts are added to the page is significant?

**Edit 2:** I just got an E-mail from another user who tried to modify the home page for the main site and got this error after clicking the edit button:

[Error Message http://dl.dropbox.com/u/8139650/SPWPFail.png](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/8139650/SPWPFail.png)

I tacked "?contents=1" onto the end of the page's URL and manually deleted the only two webparts on the page: an RSS Feed (which has never worked as it looks like it's constantly updating, something with the AJAX I think) and the failing webpart originally referenced in this question.  After deleting the webparts she was able to edit the page as normal.

Comment: Is there anything in your 14/LOGS?

Comment: @Dave Wise - I am so new to this platform that I don't know how to check that, can you let me know or link me to some instructions?

Comment: Open Central Administration > Monitoring > Diagnostics Logging > Trace Log. Check the URL specified.

Comment: @Anders Rask - I'm not finding "Diagnostics Logging", possibly because I've only recently used the "Configure diagnostic logging" link.  What am I missing?  Here's what my Monitoring page looks like: http://db.tt/9ejLA1o

Comment: click "configure diagnostics logging". Then when you have the path (typically c:\program files\common files\microsoft shared\web server extensions\14\logs ) download a log viewer such as ULS Viewer (http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/ULSViewer). With ULS Viewer you can see errors realtime as it happens

Comment: @Anders Rask - Okay, after getting ULS Viewer and checking my logs, I've got nothing.  I've had ULS Viewer open on the most recent log and replicated the problem with no result in the logs, which are set on Verbose.

Comment: Are these out of the box web parts or your own?  I've never seen an error like this but do you, or your web part, have permissions to see the information on the list you are accessing?

Comment: @MichaelF - OOB.  And yes to both on the permissions question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In lieu of an actual solution I removed the list from the main site and made it available only on the sub-site.  Not ideal, but it needed to work at least partially.

Answer (score 5):

You can go to the web part maintenance page by adding a query string parameter:

......mypage.aspx?contents=1

This will at least allow you to temporarily close the web part to render the page again without having to revert to an earlier version. You might then be able to diagnose the problem with the status list indicator, or re-add it to the page.

Comment: You get an upvote just for showing me such a neat trick.  I dunno if it's going to solve my problem yet, but I'll play with it to find out.